# What can I use to determine the proper size of faucet aerator to buy to replace the existing ones in my american standard faucet?

Tags: plumbing

My bathroom sinks have clogged up. After ruining the little "remove the aerator with a coin" plastic inserts, I bought [this tool off amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00606JS3I). It was able to get the aerator out, but the teeth don't fit correctly (they're smaller than the notches in the aerator), and the aerator that came with it doesn't fit back in the fixture (it's too long for the fixture)

Is there some reliable sizing chart I can use to determine the proper aerator for my faucet?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a pic of your faucet, specifically a close-up of the spout end?

Answer (score 5):

Any sizing chart online won't be accurate because the sizes are so close together. Your best bet is to take your old aerator to a home store. They usually have a template gauge you can screw your aerator into to determine the correct replacement size. Taking it to a plumbing supply store would also work. They could tell just by looking at it.